# Encrypt in SQL Server and decrypt in Python / spark

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, encryption

Is it possible to encrypt a column in **SQL Server** and then decrypt it in **Python cod**e?

I will need this because I'm working with many different data sources and building data extractions pipelines but there are some sensitive information that should be encrypted on some steps, such as the database one, but i need them as plain text later to process it, so the idea is to Encrypt it on the database through a SP or a built in function and then be able to decrypt it using python / spark.

If someone has another idea, please feel free to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every software have their own encryption methods, technically, it should be impossible to decrypt without involving SQL Server DB Engine if that's where you are encrypting the data. Otherwise, just anyone could decrypt sensitive data making encryption useless.

But you can call internal SQL functions from python as far as I know.

Ok let me try myself and demonstrate ->

Now this might not be the best way to use encryption/decryption but using encrypt by passphrase function from sql as a demo might just help.

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST_ENCRYPT /* CREATE DATABASE */
GO

USE TEST_ENCRYPT /* USE DATABASE */
GO

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES (ID INT IDENTITY, NAME VARCHAR(20), SALARY VARBINARY(256)) /* CREATE TABLE */
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE INSERT_DATA    /* CREATE STORED PROCEDURE THAT WILL INSERT DATA INTO TABLE */
@EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR(20), @SALARY INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @KEY VARCHAR(20) = 'testkey'   /* PASSPHRASE IS CASE SENSITVE*/
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES
        VALUES 
                (
                @EMPLOYEE_NAME,
                ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@KEY  
                    , CAST (@SALARY AS VARBINARY(256)))
                
                )

END

EXEC INSERT_DATA @EMPLOYEE_NAME = 'TIM', @SALARY = 34000 /* INSERT DATA */
```

How does my table look to my DBA?

[image]

Now to check data, your query should be like

```
DECLARE @KEY VARCHAR(20) = 'testkey'
SELECT NAME, CAST (DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE (@KEY, SALARY) AS INT) [SALARY] FROM EMPLOYEES /* CHECK DATA BY INTERNALLY DECRYPTING IN SQL SERVER */
```

[image]

But instead of running that query from within sql server, you could run from python

```
import pyodbc 
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=Blackbox;'
                      'Database=test_encrypt;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
var1 = ('testkey',)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT name, cast (DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE (?, salary) as int) [Salary] FROM test_encrypt.dbo.Employees', var1)

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

[image]

These are just one of many ways to do it. You can use certificates, keys, asymmetric keys, etc

Read documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cryptographic-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15